# Finding academic collaborations by location

Tags: citations, collaboration, networking

What is the best way to find academic collaborations between two locations (e.g. Berlin and Australia) occurring within a certain field / topic?  Some variety of massive, searchable, citation / co-author network map would be ideal, but the examples I can find so far seem quite limited.

Comment: Not exactly the same thing, but maybe worth mentioning: one can search the ResearcherID database (http://www.researcherid.com) for a specific author, and obtain a breakdown by country or a map of where his/her collaborators and citers are in the world.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can, to some extent, use traditional publications databases for that. For example, with Web of Science:

```
(CI=Berlin) AND (CU=Australia) AND (SU=Chemistry)
```

will give you the list of publications with affiliations listing both Berlin and Australia in Chemistry. You can then skim through the list, or analyze it further, for example here by institution:

[image]

---

Another way to find a destination for your next holidays can be:

1. Start with a senior colleague you know well
2. Try to see who he's been working with recently: find papers, sort by institution

   [image]
3. Pick your location and ask him to put you in contact with them!